# Next.js searches images in local directory not on AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, nextjs-image

We are converting our app to Next.js from Create React App.

Next.js should load images from AWS but this not happen. Why?

It worked some days ago. Do you think it's some caching problems or what?

Do you any ideas?

In Next.js the app loads the images from this local URL:

`http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com%2Fob8h_0.cover.jpg&w=1200&q=100`

`next.config.js`:

```js
const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require("next-i18next/rewrites");

const localeSubpaths = {
  hu: "hu",
  en: "en"
};

module.exports = {
  rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"]
  }
};
```

1 Image tag:

```js
<Image
  src={`https://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${props.imgId}_0.cover.jpg`}
  className={styles.imageEventMain}
  alt="main event"
  layout="responsive"
  width={1795}
  height={1000}
  quality={100}
/>;
```

In React there wasn't problems with AWS or image loading.

***EDIT***

console.log when trying to access the images:

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors when the image tries to load on your app? Can you access the image directly from the browser?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the console to the question.

Im accessing those images in the Create React App at the same Url, what I have to convert to Next.js.

I think the main problem is Next wants to load the images from localhost, but they are on AWS

Comment: The image is served from localhost because since you're using `next/image` Next.js will use its built-in image optimization to optimize the image and serve it.

Comment: It's ok, I understand this now, but in that case why the images unavailable on localhost, on that route where next.js cached them?

Comment: @GyarmatiIstván Did you end up solving this? facing same issue

Comment: images for me on localhost are also failing (400 error). Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this:

Change:

```
module.exports = {
  rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"]
  }
};
```

To:

```
module.exports = {
  rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths
  },
  images: {
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "https://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/",
    domains: ["ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"]
  }
};
```

Change your Image component like this:

```
<Image
  src={`${props.imgId}_0.cover.jpg`}
  className={styles.imageEventMain}
  alt="main event"
  layout="responsive"
  width={1795}
  height={1000}
  quality={100}
/>;
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: If it worked for @Gyarmati István, please mark it as Accepted Answer.

Comment: what is the purpose of key `loader` in image configuration?